# Slider manual control to allow prev/next button to click from last slide to first slide

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get https://jsfiddle.net/t8ap0gvz/4/ to allow the prev/next buttons to navigate between the first and last slide. Currently you can navigate 1-12 with prev/next buttons or gallery buttons however if user is on slide 1 and tries to click previous button to get to 12 it won't allow it and if user is on slide 12 and tries to click next button to get to slide 1 it won't allow it. How do I allow this option

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

showSlides();

function showSlides() {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
  slideIndex = 1
}
slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}

function currentSlide(no) {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
slideIndex = no;
slides[no - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function plusSlides(n) {
var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
if (newslideIndex < 13 && newslideIndex > 0) {
  currentSlide(newslideIndex);
}
}
```

Comment: A hint I can give you would be to "reset" the count if it's less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add some additional conditions to your function `plusSlides(n)` like this

```
  function plusSlides(n) {
    var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
    if (newslideIndex < 13 && newslideIndex > 0) {
      currentSlide(newslideIndex);
    }
    else if (newslideIndex > 12){
        currentSlide(1)
    }
    else currentSlide(12)
  }
```